# how can lein midje :autotest be made to work with immutant?

Tags: clojure, midje, immutant

I'm migrating a application I did in ring over to immutant and and a bit lost as to what to do with all my tests.

Because immutant projects are required to be deployed, what is the best strategy to test the functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` task of the `lein-immutant` plugin will fire up Immutant, deploy your app, run all its tests, undeploy the app, and shutdown the Immutant.

It's really meant as more of a CI process, though. When developing your app, it's best to be connected to your app deployed in Immutant at a REPL. That way, you can eval your tests as you go.

Currently, the `test` task doesn't directly support midje facts, but you can wrap them in a deftest to trigger them ala https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Lein-test

Comment: Update: Recent versions of lein-immutant have been patched to autodetect Midje in the remote project and run its test suite if found. You can now just do "lein immutant test" to kick this process off.